# Why doesn't the printf statement execute here after entering some text and pressing the "enter" key (EOF)?

Tags: c, printf, eof

The code, derived from "The C Programming Language, Second Edition":

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  long nc;

  nc = 0;
  while(getchar() != EOF)
    ++nc;
  printf("%s: %ld\n", "number of characters", nc); 
}
```

Why doesn't the "printf" statement execute after pressing the "enter" key (EOF)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The enter key is **not** EOF. Depending on your system, it will send a carriage return (0x0D or `'\r'`), a line feed (0x0A or `'\n'`), or both.

On Linux (and probably Unix), EOF can be sent by Ctrl+D. On Windows it should be Ctrl+Z (but you might need to press enter afterwards).

Comment: Bah, beat me to it.  Good answer.

Comment: Perhaps there's a defined EOL character for the system OP could use?

Comment: Thank you! Solved. I'll post a follow-up question related to this later today.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute that `printf` after hitting the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, you should change it from:

```
while(getchar() != EOF)
```

to:

```
while(getchar() != '\n')
```

EOF (end of file) is not the same as ENTER.

And you might want to consider getting a more up to date book.

Comment: Hi. Any recommendations on another book?